# Could not get trait set for device MacFamily20,1 with version 14.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting this warning for a brandnew Xcode 12.3 iOS project:

> Could not get trait set for device MacFamily20,1 with version 14.2

in Assets.xcassets

[image]

My build target is "My Mac (Designed for iPad)" on a MacBook Air M1

What does it mean? How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

This only happens in **Debug** mode. If you try building in **Release** mode It will be disappear.

Answer (score 0):

In the Deployment Info (Target - General), the Designed for iPad is available only if you select the Option Mac, select it and unselect Mac option.