# SpriteKit Could not get trait set for device iPad14,5 with version 16.2

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, xcasset

I have seen similar questions before but they had no answers.
Could somebody help with this problem?
[image]

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65509101/could-not-get-trait-set-for-device-macfamily20-1-with-version-14-2

Comment: Yes, I've seen. But there is no real help there.

Comment: I'm getting the following warning `…Assets.xcassets: Could not get trait set for device iPad14,3 with version 16.4` after I upgraded to Xcode 14.3 recently. The warning only shows when I build debug config to an iPad simulator.

Answer (score 7):

I created a new empty asset catalog (with the idea to try to move the old stuff into it), and the warning disappeared... go figure.

Comment: I got this warning on 14.3 and creating and deleting an additional asset catalog in the same target as the one where the warning is made the warning go away. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`